# Vector macro on array variable?

Tags: rust

Just curious, is there a way to define a Vector with the `vec!` macro on an array variable?

The bellow code compiles fine:

```
let a = [1,2,3,4]
let v = vec![1,2,3,4]
```

But I get a `mismatched types` error when compiling this:

```
let a = [1,2,3,4]
let v = vec!a
```

This seems like it should intuitively work but I'm coming from Python so I often expect little shortcuts like that and that sometimes leads me astray.  What's the best way to quickly initialize a Vector with the values in an already-existent array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just convert the `slice` to a `Vector` with [`a.to_vec()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec).

Rust macro is defined so that it can be used against specific patterns of expression. A simplified `vec!`, for instance, can be found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html). As you can see from the definition, the expression must match pattern defined as `( $( $x:expr ),* )`, i.e. the pattern must be enclosed with a pair of parenthesis to begin with. Expression `a` doesn't match this pattern.

Comment: Ah that's easy enough.  Could you help me understand why the posted solution doesn't work?  I'm not understanding the error message so well.

Comment: @SamDillard it's because what you wrote isn't actually valid syntax - macro invocations are always the name of the macro, then the exclamation point, and then something like parentheses (in this case braces), and everything inside that is then matched to the patterns inside the macro definition if possible.

Comment: Your posted solution is how you would use a method / function. But macro is not a function, the expression used with macro must match the pattern defined for the macro.